# How the input entered through the front-end form match with the existing data in database

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin

Am working on an application that helps user to enter symptoms that matches those existing in the database and gets disease(diagnosis).

I have the following database table with information about symptoms, diseases, and disease-symptoms which associates the two tables, as shown below:

```
DISEASE_T   SYMPTOMS    disease-symptoms
==========  ==========  ========

DISEASE_ID  SYMPTOM_ID  DISEASE_ID

VALUE       VALUE       SYMPTOM_ID
```

I want to search user selected symptoms, which are array of symptoms id in disease-symptoms table and return top 5 matching disease IDs, based on, where most of the symptoms are matching with each disease.

For example, user select symptoms are 1,2,3 (cough,cold,headache)

```
DISEASE_T      SYMPTOMS_T  disease-symptoms

=========      ==========  ===============

1,malaria       1,cough          1,1

2,tuberculosis  2,cold           1,2

3,typhoid       3,headache       2,2
                                 2,3
                                 3,1
                                 3,2
                                 3,3
```

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: In your example, is the correct answer 3 or 3 followed by 1,2? 3 is the only disease that matches all three symptoms, but should the result also contain partial matches?

Comment: The output doesn't matter a lot but generating the right logic to get that disease after entering the input from the form.For instance `if  1 and 2 entered then malaria is the result`  hope you get the hint here

Answer (score 1):

Select diseases with the 3 symptoms:

select DISEASE_ID, count(*)
  from DiseaseSymptoms_T
 where SYMPTOM_ID in (1, 2, 3)
 group by DISEASE_ID
having count(*) = 3  -- number of symptoms in the where

That will only list typhoid, because it has all three symptoms

If you want all the diseases with the symptoms 1 and 2

select DISEASE_ID, count(*)
  from DiseaseSymptoms_T
 where SYMPTOM_ID in (1, 2)
 group by DISEASE_ID
having count(*) = 2  -- number of symptoms in the where

This last query will also show the disease typhoid, because it has the two symptoms in the where

If you want only the first 5 rows, the syntax depends on the engine. For SQL Server use SELECT TOP 5 DISEASE_ID... For MySQL add LIMIT 1 at the end of the query... For Informix use SELECT FIRST 5...